# changing CSS of right part of top-bar-section in foundation

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I ma trying to create responsive mega menu with foundation,the problem is that i try every thing but i can't change the color of the right part of my menu it is still black.i change the color of top-bar and it is gray now but the .top-bar-section doesn't change.here is my CSS code:

```
    .top-bar{
    background-color:gray !important;
}

    .top-bar .expanded{
        background-color:gray !important;

}
.top-bar-section ul li.active>a{
    color:black !important;
    background-color:gray !important;
}

    .mega-menu {
        border-top: 1px solid #222;
    }
    .mega-menu .top-bar-section .right> li{
        background-color:blue !important;
    }
        /* Change tab hover state to same colour as content background */
        .mega-menu .top-bar .top-bar-section li:hover > a {
            color: #222;
            background: #FFF;
        }
```

I want to change the background color of the  in top-bar-section,but it dosen't change
here is a part of my code:

```
<div class="mega-menu">
        <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar="">
            <ul class="title-area">
                <li class="name">
                    <h1><a href="#">Tojjar</a></h1>
                </li>
                <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#"><span>Menu</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <section class="top-bar-section">

                <ul class="right">
                    <li><a><strong class="fontstyle">درباره ما</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a><strong class="fontstyle">راهنما</strong></a></li>
                    <li><a><strong class="fontstyle">تماس با ما</strong></a></li>
```

thanks.

Comment: You can simply change the top-bar setting https://github.com/zurb/foundation/blob/master/scss/foundation/components/_top-bar.scss and build Foundation from SASS

Answer (score 0):

On my most recent install of FoundationPress, I believe it was the following two properties:

```
.top-bar-section li.active:not(.has-form) a:not(.button) {background:$color !important;}
```

And

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em){.top-bar-section li:not(.has-form) a:not(.button):hover {background:$color !important;}}
```

And that side block matched the color I wanted.

(The top-bar color didn't change those two settings)